# Setting up Multiple WAN Static IP

Tags: networking

We purchased a 5 Static IP Address package from Rogers and we need to use two IPs. The Rogers modem has 4 ports in the back of it so I plugged in two routers (one on each modem port). I then configured each Router with the relevant Static IP and we were online.

We've been having random disconnects where a 3-4 times each day we'd have to restart the modem to get things stable. I verified this by connecting to a computer over TeamViewer just to see TeamViewer disconnect and reconnect 3-4 times a day.

So we had the Rogers guy back in to replace the modem and he said that we should only be plugging into a single port on the modem. I realize the ports may not be individual interfaces but more like a switch but now I don't know what type of router will handle multiple WAN IPs over a single connection.

I have attached the recommended configuration diagram and I'm wondering what feature this is that allows such a connection so I can select a router. I would also like it if someone can recommend a router that can handle this type of setup.

Thanks so much for any help!

[image: Rogers Recommended Networking]

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic, but virtually any commercial grade router will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Install a switch between the rogers modem and the routers, that case you will be capable of using the IP's by connecting the firewall/router on any port of that switch.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what type of router will handle multiple WAN IPs over a single connection.

Almost any. If I'd had to find a (business) router that is capable of only one WAN Interface IP, I wouldn't knwo where to look.